# How to stop the Observable.timer which is used through observable operators like debounceTime and switchMap for asynchronous validations

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to stop the Observable.timer when I navigate from that page to another page.
Below is the code which I'm using in my project.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable, Subject}from 'RxJs/Rx';

export class SettingsPage extends BasePage implements OnDestroy {
ionViewDidLoad() {
let initial: boolean = true;

this.serverUrlStream
        .debounce((val)=> Observable.timer(initial ? 0 : 500))  
        .switchMap(val => {     
                this.canLeave = false;  
                this.apiClientService.ocServiceUrl = val;
                return Observable.fromPromise(this.apiClientService.getHospitals());
        })
        .catch((err, caught)=>{
            console.log(err);
            return caught;  // Continue after error
        })
        .subscribe((hospitals: Hospital[]) => {
            this.hospitals = hospitals;
            if (hospitals.length > 0) {
                this.settings.hospitalInstallId = hospitals[0].InstallId;
                this.canLeave = true;                   
                this.cd.detectChanges();
            }
        });


    this.serverUrlStream.next(this.settings.serverUrl);
    initial = false;
}
//I tried like below to stop the timer when I left from this page.

ngOnDestroy(){
this.serverUrlStream.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Above code is not working still ajax call is running every 5 seconds. Can anyone please help me to stop the Observable.timer when user leave the current page

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with unsubscribing in `ngOnDestroy` is the correct one. You just got the syntax slightly wrong.

You first need to assign the actual subscription to a variable, like this
`this.serverUrlSubscription = this.serverUrlStream.debounce(...)...subscribe(...);`

where you  should declare `serverUrlSubscription: Subscription;` as a member of your class first (`Subscription` type can be imported from `rxjs/Subscription`).

You can then simply do `this.serverUrlSubscription.unsubscribe();` in your `ngOnDestroy` to detach and destroy the *subscription*.

A second approach would be to use `takeUntil(this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart)` after the `switchMap` operator, where you'd first have to inject the angular router to `this.router`.

But i would recommend you use `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: Tried with ngdestroy as per your comments but still it is not working.

Comment: is `ngOnDestroy` triggering when you expect it to? I'm not really very familiar with ionic - perhaps the Page object isn't destroyed when navigating away from it. You could try the second approach in this case, although there may be an ionic router you have to look into using then.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I place the take until code after the switchmap.. Error: Argument of type '(hospitals: Hospital[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'hospitals' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'Hospital[]'.
      Type 'NavigationStart' is not assignable to type 'Hospital[]'.
        Property 'length' is missing in type 'NavigationStart'.

Comment: My code: this.serverUrlStream
   .debounce((val)=> Observable.timer(initial ? 0 : 500)) 
   .filter(val => !!val)
   .switchMap(val =>{  
    this.apiClientService.ocServiceUrl = val;
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.apiClientService.getHospitals());
   })
   .catch((err, caught)=>{
    
    return caught;
   }).takeUntil(this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart)
   .subscribe((hospitals: Hospital[]) => {
    this.hospitals = hospitals;
    if (hospitals.length > 0) {
     this.settings.hospitalInstallId = hospitals[0].InstallId; 
    }
   });

Comment: you need to close the takeUntil() before .subscribe().

Comment: According to https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/ you could also try to use `unsubscribe()` as initially suggested but hook into `ionViewDidLeave` or `ionViewWillLeave`. It might be the better approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. FYI.. I tried with ionViewWillLeave also the issue will be the same. I just want to abort the http ajax call which is calling in all pages. Please help me on this

Comment: Did you close the `takeUntil()` before calling `subscribe()`, as mentioned in my earlier comment? In the code you provided (comment) you were subscribing to the `router.event` stream, which is not what you should be doing. You should just provide `takeUntil()` with the router stream (and close it), but subscribe to the original `debounce.switchMap` stream, just like you did originally.

takeUntil should then close the stream as soon as the router emits an NavigationStart event, destroying the subscription. Whether the router emits a NavigationStart event in Ioinc, i do not know.

Comment: Yes i close the takeUntil() but in ionic we don't have routing so it is not working in my project. I think as you said above we need to fix this by ngOnDestroy. Let me know any other approach for this. Thanks.